# Best way to handle an uploaded file until all checks are done

Tags: php, frameworks, filesystems

In my case, at the end, uploaded files will be stored in a storage path, not publicly available and the relative path is saved in a database.

Now i would like some advices on how to handle the uploaded files (initially in a tmp directory). Then, after basic checks on the request parameters and the uploaded file, I will move it to the storage path and store the relative path.

What about unexpected errors? What to do if there is an error in the db for instance? Should I find a way to catch the error and then remove the uploaded file? Should I predict the final path (without moving the file) until the saving is done, then move the file? Other ideas?

What would be the best procedure to handle that cases please?

Comment: periodically check on the temp file directory and if any file exist past the maximum amount of time you would ever be validating and uploading a file. If found then delete it. That should take care of any files left in temp because of an error somewhere else. However try to handle the actual errors and take care of files at that time if possible this would be a last case directory cleaner.

Comment: The OS is already taking care of the system temp directory (usually /tmp). But this doesn’t solve the question “should I insert to db before moving the file to its final path, or should I move before inserting to db then delete if error, or something else?”. Is it clearer ?

Comment: Wouldn't either way work fine as long as you have code in place to correct it if an errors occurs. If the error happens at the DB or at the file level when moving it you end up needing to take care of both situations anyway. If you move the file first and there is a DB error then you have to remove the file. If you insert to the DB first then error while moving the file then you have to remove from the DB so either way I would think.

Comment: There is no clear way to tell you what to do. Are you planning to handle the file checks during a web request or are you going to use some back end process? How do you plan to notify the person who uploaded the file?

Comment: @ryantxr everything will be done during the same request. In case of error, the user would be redirected back to the form with an error message

Comment: You have to decide how you want to store your data. You can wait to store the information in your database and move the file until you know the file is good.  Or you can store and move the file, then if it fails, mark it in your database as bad.